# Clicking on DIV with id

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to make selenium-webdriver click on a div with the id of "send-button"

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Send anonymously')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("send-button)).click();
```

```
(async function example() {
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();
    try {
      await driver.get('https://onyolo.com/VFUF5VtxPJ');
      await driver.findElement(By.name('text')).sendKeys('test', Key.RETURN);
      await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Send anonymously')]")).click();
      await driver.wait(until.reload);
    } finally {
      await driver.quit();
    }
  })();
```

html code on website

```
<div id="send-button">Send anonymously</div>
```

Comment: hi welcome to stack overflow, please state your goal and the problem.

Comment: I am trying to make selenium-webdriver js version click on a div with the id of "send-button" I am unsure of how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can run pure javascript with `executeScript` method.

`` await driver.executeScript(`document.getElementById('send-button').click()`); ``

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss providing the right xpath?
you've used 'a' instead of 'div'

//div[contains(text(),'Send anonymously')]